# sorting - wp_query using meta_value_num is not working

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

i've seen some questions on this but the answers were not clear and definite.

i have a custom query, each of the posts in that custom post type have a custom field named "**my_order**" with a numeric value. whatever i tried i cannot get them to sort by that value. **any clue** ?

```
   <?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_value_num' => 'my_order' 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'my_order'
            )
        )
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

silly me,

it should be **'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'**
and 'meta_key' => 'my_order'

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'my_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'

);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thanks...

Comment: np glad it helped you get to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work for you?

```
   <?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_value_num' => 'my_order' 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'meta_key' => 'my_order'
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```